# Situations where extension of contraction is well-behaved?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

It is known that one cannot expect the extension of the contraction of an ideal under a ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$ to be the original ideal, except in very special scenarios like surjections or localizations. In [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708801/contractions-and-extensions-of-ideals-and-faithful-flatness) we see this does not even happen if the map is faithfully flat; however in the example given (i.e. $k[x^2]\subseteq k[x]$ and the ideal $xk[x]$) the extension of the contraction has the original ideal as its radical. This the leads to the question

> Are there sufficient conditions (e.g. faithfully flat, (faithfully) finite etale) which could ensure that $\sqrt{(\mathfrak b\cap A)B}$ equals (or is otherwise related to in a reasonable way) $\mathfrak b$ for radical ideals $\mathfrak b\subseteq B$?

Comment: Notice that the property means that $\varphi : \mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ satisfies a topological property: for all closed subsets $T \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(B)$ we have $$T = \varphi^{-1}(\overline{\varphi(T)}).$$